Angular RxJs encapsulate subscription in called function
When we learn about subscribing to Observables a common example goes uses http requests:
given a service method to retrieve data over http, a component calls this method, the method returns an Observable and the component subscribes to the Observable. Eventually the result of the api call is assigned to a component property:
in apiService.ts
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get(...)
}

in myComponent.ts:
apiService.getPosts()
   .subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts)

This looks ugly. A service is used to encapsulate logic but here the logic is divided between the service that makes an asynchronous http call and the calling component that subscribes to the returned Observable.
I want both to be in the service so that I can do
in myComponent.ts:
this.posts = apiService.getPosts()

Is this possible? And how do we manage errors when moving subscription code to service?

Yes. You can do this. this.posts = apiService.getPosts(). Now, posts is observable variable. You need to use async pipe to subscribe it from template. like this  <div *ngIf="posts | async as postsRecord"> {{postRecords}} </div>

Yes, that is an option in Angular. My question was more general - is it possible without resorting to Angular specific constructs like pipes that implicit subscribe at the callers side?

Marc, "A service should return Observables, you subscribe in your components". It's the "most natural". Really use Promise (personal opinion) is a "steps backward"

you can use await and firstValueFrom which is exported rom rxjs which will basically convert an observal to promise Read Here
make your function async put try and catch for error handling
For ex
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

async getPosts() {
    try {
        this.posts = await firstValueFrom(apiService.getPosts());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}


A third possibility is to use a BehaviorSubject whose next() gets called with the result of the http.get(). The component subscribes to the BehaviorSubject and updates a component property with the result of te http.get():
in ApiService
export class ApiService {
  private URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  public PostSubject$: BehaviorSubject<Post[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Post[]>([]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPosts(): void {
    this.http.get<Post[]>(this.URL)
      .pipe(
        tap((allPosts: Post[]) => this.PostSubject$.next(allPosts))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}

in component.ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  posts: Post[] = [];
  
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    // subscribe to postSubject
    this.api.PostSubject$.subscribe(this.posts = posts)
  }

 ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getPosts();
  }

}


How does it different from your question? I think this is over engineering. Directly subscribe from http service into the component is what you need. Plus use async is favorable to not have to manually unsubscribe management.

Plus, Use subjects only when for actions$ streams. Like to pass filter object action or to pass Id and get new data. This any user action is called action$ stream and for that subject is advisable to use.

Create async function where you can call API, get response and return it.
async getPosts(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const posts = await this.http.get<any>(...).toPromise();
      return posts;
    } catch (error) {      
      throw error;
    }
  }

Now, store retuned value in your this.post
try {
    this.posts = await this.apiService.getPosts();
} catch (error) {     
    console.error('Error fetching posts:', error);
}

